# Button highlighted after click

Tags: css

I want my application's buttons to be green only when I hover over them. Currently, they are green after I click one of them, until I click something else.

[image]

For instance, this button is green after clicking on it and before clicking somewhere else.

What's the name of this effect?

I am now looking over my `css` files, trying to find this effect and replace it with `hover` so that the buttons are green only when I hover over them.

Comment: Maybe until it has **FOCUS**?

Comment: have you checked :focus pseudo-class properties for the button?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Then check with dev tools. You will see which rules are applied and why

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is applying the style to the [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-class.

> The :focus CSS pseudo-class is applied when an element has received
>   focus, either from the user selecting it with the use of a keyboard or
>   by activating with the mouse (e.g. a form input).

Alternately, the style might be applied by JavaScript in response to click/focus events, either directly to the element, or by adding a class to the element.

As mentioned in the comments by @AdrianoRepetti, use dev tools to help identify how the style is being applied.

Comment: :focus is not a selector by itself, but a keyword added to selectors.

Comment: I replaced `focus` with `hover` everywhere in the `css` but the issue remains.